# Disable click handler when click is fired in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a website built in .NET and jQuery. We have custom jQuery to call the load method on a processing ASP.NET page. That ajax call is fired in a click handler, e.g.

```
$("#Submit").click(function(){
  $(a_selector).load("Process.aspx?data=" + someDataObject, null, function(){
    alert("Done")});
  }
  return false;
);
```

Our issue is when we hit the #Submit button the click is fired which calls the ajax to process it. People seem to be double-clicking the button and therefore we're getting multiple results in our database from the dual clicks. Does anyone have an idea on how to prevent this issue? I considered something like disabling the button via JS but I'd like to know of other ideas.

Comment: what's wrong with the disabling the button idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[stop propagation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29)

```
$("#Submit").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();

  if (typeof $_submitSend == "undefined")
      var $_submitSend = true;
  else if ($_submitSend == true)
      return false;

  $_submitSend = true;

  $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");

  $(a_selector).load("Process.aspx?data=" + someDataObject, null, function(){
    alert("Done")});
    $_submitSend = false;
    $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`one` function](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/one#typedatafn) of jQuery. This way, the event is only ever fired once. Of course, you should also disable the button so the user knows that clicking on it is futile. In addition, show a spinner, progress bar, or change the cursor styling to indicate to the user that something is happening and the system isn't stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Submit").click(function(){
  $(a_selector).removeClass("class").load("Process.aspx?data=" + someDataObject, null, function(){
    $(this).addClass("class");
    alert("Done")});
  }
  return false;
);
```

Then just add some specific class without any styling which you will use as a selector. Dont know if it will work the way you want, but it looks like simplest solution to me... :)